# Remove single node from unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

The program should print 'Yes' if all words contained in note appear in magazine (case-sensitive), otherwise print 'No'. Each word in magazine can only be used once, that is, if the note has the same word twice the magazine must also contain that word at least twice.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void checkMagazine(vector<string> magazine, vector<string> note) {

    // Inserts magazine vector into an unordered_map for quick access
    unordered_map<string, int> umap;
    for (auto& x : magazine)
        umap[x] = 1;    

    // For each word in note search the unordered_map for that word
    for (auto& word : note) {
        if (umap.find(word) == umap.end()) { // Word not in magazine
            cout << "No" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else    // Remove single instance of that word
            umap.erase(word);
    }

    cout << "Yes" << endl;
    return;
}


int main()
{
    vector<string> magazine = { "Help", "me", "please", "please" };
    vector<string> note = { "Help", "please", "please" };

    checkMagazine(magazine, note);

    return 0;
}
```

The else condition needs to remove that single node from umap (or only a single instance of that particular word) but to the best of my knowledge the only modifier that can do this is 'extract' but **I cannot use C++17**.

Is there a way I can work around this, or is this type of method not going to work with an unordered_map?
Would a linked list be more appropriate? I'm new to data structures so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could instead keep a count for number of times a word appears, and subtract it every time you match it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something of this nature. I wrote it without much thought and without checking, so take it with a grain of salt (probably is correct). The idea is to use count of number of times a word appears in a magazine and substract it whenever you find it in the note.

```
    unordered_map<string, int> mp;
    for(const auto& s: magazine) mp[s]++;
    for(const auto& s: note) {
        auto it = mp.find(s);
        if(it == mp.end() || it->second <= 0) { cout << "No"; return; }
        it->second--; // if(!--it->second) mp.erase(it);  
        if(!it->second) mp.erase(it); 
    }
    cout << "Yes";
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That also clears up why the mp[s]++ in your case uses ++ rather than =1 like in my example - it tallies up the node counter for repeats because an unordered_map doesn't make duplicates (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes, you have it right, generally speaking you wanna make sure to use the second value to hold some information, a simple is it in or not lookup can be performed on a set too after all.